# MongoDB: Looking for advice on designing schema for improving query efficiency

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I’m looking for advice on designing the schema before I commit to going down this route. I’m developing a collaborative documentation system, where the user creates a document and invites other users to collaborate, much like Google docs.

There are two collections. The first one stores documents and the second one stores lists of collaborators. When the user creates a new document, they assign a list of collaborators to this document. In the simplest form, the schema would look something like this

The Document schema contains some data but it also maintains a reference to a document in the Collaborators collection

Document model

```
  {
       ....
      collaborators: ObjectId; // e.g. 0x507f1f77bcf86cd799439011
    }
```

Collaborators collection contains documents that contain an array of roles for the collaborators.

Collaborators model

```
{
     _id: 0x507f1f77bcf86cd799439011; // refererenced by Document model
    collaborators: [
        {userId: 1, role: "editor"},
        {userId: 2, role: "commenter}
   ]
}
```

I will have an API that fetches all those documents where the logged-in user’s userId is in the list of collaborators referenced by the document. Without much experience with writing efficient queries, I think a two-step lookup will work but it won’t be very efficient.

Step 1 → Find all the collaborators lists which contain userId, and obtain their _id field

Step 2 → Find all documents that have collaborators field containing one of the values found in Step 1

Is there a more efficient way to construct this query particularly if the users fetch this list frequently?

If I should redesign the schema in some way so that the lookup can be efficient, I’d like to know.

I'm using mongoose client if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I realized using MongoDB aggregation framework is what I needed. I was able to use `$lookup` and `$match` stage to achieve what I want. Still not sure how expensive this is given that $lookup will perform left join.

Here’s an example if anybody wants to look.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPheBZESC0H

Comment: `"collaborators.list.userId"` is and array. and `"collaborators.list.userId":1` will pass all list, as long 1 userid=1 , if you want to keep only 1 you have to filter the array. `$lookup` will be very fast as long as you have indexes in join fields.